# How do I apply a macro to multiple excel files when the macro contains many subs?

Tags: vba

I have used a macro to track changes in a workbook, but I would now like to run this macro in over a 100 excel files within a particular folder using a Do While Loop.

I am very new to VBA and will appreciate all the help I can get.

I have come across some code that should enable me to loop through excel files in a folder and run the macro in each one.

However it requires me to get rid of the 'sub' and 'end sub' from the macro when I copy and paste it into the do while loop, but I have 3 of them within the macro; some variables will be undefined if I delete all 3.

Therefore I tried 'Call Tracker' within the loop ('Tracker' being the macro name) and hoped it would run in each excel file.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String

    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*,xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
           With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                'Your code here
                Call Tracker
           End With
           xFileName = Dir
        Loop
     End If
End Sub
```

Below is the code inside 'Tracker'

```
Option Explicit
Dim sOldAddress As String
Dim vOldValue As Variant

Public Sub Workbook_TrackChange(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sh.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&06" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbLf & "&A"
    Next Sh
End Sub

Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Set wActSheet = ActiveSheet

     'Precursor Exits
     'Other conditions that you do not want to track could be added here
    If vOldValue = "" Then Exit Sub 'If you comment out this line *every* entry will be recorded

     'Continue

    On Error Resume Next ' This Error-Resume-Next is only to allow the creation of the tracker sheet.
    Set wSheet = Sheets("Tracker")
     '**** Add the tracker Sheet if it does not exist ****


    If wSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set wActSheet = ActiveSheet
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Tracker"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
     '**** End of specific error resume next

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Sheets("Tracker")
         '******** This bit of code moves the tracker over a column when the first columns are full**'
        If .Cells(1, 1) = "" Then '
            iCol = 1 '
        Else '
            iCol = .Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column - 7 '
            If Not .Cells(65536, iCol) = "" Then '
                iCol = .Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 '
            End If '
        End If '
         '********* END *****************************************************************************'
        .Unprotect Password:="Secret"

         '******** Sets the Column Headers **********************************************************
        If LenB(.Cells(1, iCol).Value) = 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(1, iCol + 7)) = Array("Cell Changed", "SAP ID", "Field Name", "Old Field Value", _
            "New Field Value", "Time of Change", "Date Stamp", "User")
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
        End If

        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            If Target.Count = 1 Then
                .Offset(0, 1) = Cells(Target.Row, 2) 'SAPID
            End If

            '.Offset(0, 1) = Cells(Target.Row, 2) 'SAPID

            If Target.Count = 1 Then
                .Offset(0, 2) = Cells(Target.Column) 'Field name
            End If

            '.Offset(0, 2) = Cells(Target.Column) 'Field name

            .Value = sOldAddress

            .Offset(0, 3).Value = vOldValue

            If Target.Count = 1 Then
                .Offset(0, 4).Value = Target.Value
            End If

            .Offset(0, 5) = Time
            .Offset(0, 6) = Date
            .Offset(0, 7) = Application.UserName
            .Offset(0, 7).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With

         .Protect Password:="Secret"  'comment to protect the "tracker tab"

    End With
ErrorExit:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    wActSheet.Activate
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
     'any error handling you want
     'Debug.Print "We have an error"
    Resume ErrorExit

End Sub

Public Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        sOldAddress = .Address(external:=True)

        If .Count > 1 Then

            vOldValue = "Multiple Cell Select"

        Else

            vOldValue = .Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

'Call Tracker' in the loop does not produce an error. In fact the code seems to execute and loops through all the files but it does not run the macro in each one it opens.

Comment: Tracker needs to be in a standard module. Code within the workbook module can only be run on that workbook. Cut and paste tracker into a standard module

Comment: What is inside Tracker?

Comment: Is the comma in `*,xls*` a typo just here or also in your code?

Comment: Tracker is inside a standard module

Comment: The ',' is a typo

Comment: When a new workbook is opened and you can see its window, can you check if macros are enabled in that file?

Comment: I will send what is inside the Tracker

Comment: The macros are enabled in the new workbook

Comment: It seems to loop through the files, but it doesn't run the macro in each file.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the line Call Tracker, and enter the call with F8 after it stopped and see what happens?

Comment: You can now view the code inside the Tracker above.

Comment: I will have a go at what you've just suggested. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any function in the Tracker code that was called Tracker. You have to select a function that you want to call.

Comment: @z32a7ul I have tried this and it goes straight to the module containing the Sub Tracker()

Comment: @z32a7ul, I ran the code from 'ThisWorkbook' (in VBA Project) and then created macro name 'Tracker' for it. This automatically created a Sub Tracker() in another module.

Comment: @z32a7ul, This is what I called upon in the loop.

Comment: So, where is Sub Tracker located, and what is its code?

Comment: @z32a7ul, It is located in 'Module1'

Comment: And what is the code of Sub Tracker?

Comment: @z32a7ul, It's empty, as this was automatically created when I tried to run the code from 'ThisWorkbook' code sheet. I was prompted to create a Macro Name to be able to execute the code and once I did the Macro Name 'Tracker' appeared in 'Module1' as Sub Tracker.

Comment: @z32a7ul, I now have to choose this macro name every time I wish to run the code.

Comment: @z32a7ul That is why I chose to call Tracker (Macro Name).

Comment: Do you have the faintest idea of what you would like to do?